# What's the easiest way to convert a 'pretty printed' JSON string to a compact format representation?

Tags: json, swift, format

This may be an odd question as it's specific to the JSON strings themselves, not the objects they represent.  Given a 'pretty printed' JSON string (representing *any* JSON-encodable model), how would one reformat it to the 'compact' format?

My first thought was to not consider it JSON, but rather just a string, then use RegEx to remove duplicate spaces, remove newlines, etc., but that's not context aware so it risks affecting the keys and values portions of the JSON if you don't properly test that you're inside quotes.

My next thought was to try and construct an object from the JSON, but without a type to convert to, I'm not sure how to do that without manually parsing the values as 'ANY', then testing if they're an array, and recurse into it if they are, repeating the process.  Then once I have the final object, serialize the result in compact form. However, that seems like a lot of overkill.

Is there an easier way to accomplish this?  We're using Swift 4 if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**:

as pointed by @Mark A. Donohoe, this removes ALL whitespaces. so even though it looks coooooool, it's a dumb answer. don't fall for it.

---

i needed the same thing and i ended up creating a String extension:

```
extension String {
    func toCompactJSON() -> String {
        self.filter { !$0.isWhitespace && !$0.isNewline }
    }
}
```

in my case though it was for testing purposes and it turned out to be useless as the order in which the Javascript object/arrays appear is not the same as while generated through the `JSONEncoder`.

Comment: Wouldn't your code remove whitespace in strings? For instance, `{"value":"This is a test"}` would become `{"value":"Thisisatest"}`. Then again you did say this didn't work. (Side-note: for that reason you may want to remove this so you don't get down-voted which affects your rep. They aren't always the nicest here.) Another side-note, you may want to put such things in a `JSONHelper` class rather than extending `String` as extensions should generally make sense for any instance, not a specific use-case such as JSON here. Purely opinion but it's served me well and keeps the API surface clean.

Comment: @MarkA.Donohoe ah yes. very good point. currently my tests are minimal and i haven't touched the complicated ones. that whitespace issue would have been made clear later on. thanks. thanks also for the `JSONHelper` idea. i'm very new to Swift, coming from PHP, but i mainly just go through TDD, and build only what's enough to make the tests pass. and refactor later. currently my `extension` was even in the test file. would have moved it further down the path, and probably would have created a class for it, yes.

regarding the reputation, no worries. don't need approval. will try dv myself :D